# Control of Unity3D web player's camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity-web-player

Is it possible to control the camera in a Unity3D project being played on the Web player?

I want to control the walk through of existing models using JavaScript in the web player.

I see they have API functions for calling internal functions defined within the script, but don't see any way to gain access to the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By API, I assume you mean the `SendMessage` approach outlined in [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html). That is indeed the best way to approach this. Write a script which controls your camera, expose functions you can call, and call those using the

```
function ControlCamera()
{
    u.getUnity().SendMessage("MyCamera", "Control", "");
}
```

approach.

Other than that, to the best of my knowledge, there is no real exposure of a full API that lets you control GameObjects or components attached to them from JavaScript in the manner you seem to be requesting.

Comment: I thought of that approach, but it requires adding a function to that project. I want to be able to control ANY project, whether I have access to edit it or not. Sounds like its not possible?

Comment: I don't know of a way @Bill and to the best of my knowledge it does not exist.